# Why doesn't my HP laptop charge when it's powered on but it charges when it's off?

Tags: power-electronics

I changed the output charge pin. It has two wires inside but the one I removed had three. Is the problem coming from there?

Comment: What was the reason for changing the output charge pin?

Comment: Some HP laptops (mainly the business models) need those 3 connection adapters. It is a safety precaution to prevent the laptop overloading the power adapter. You should only use this laptop with the original 3 connection supply. I bet that this is also mentioned in the manual.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Questions on repair of things are off topic here. It will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not complete, but the answer is probably in the third pin.

The supply with three pins is probably the original supply. The third pin will signal to the laptop that the supply can handle a certain amount of current (using a proprietary protocol) and will allow the laptop to charge while being powered on.

When the signal on that pin is absent, the laptop cannot determine how much power is available for charging and will only allow running the laptop without charging, or will allow charging only while the laptop is powered off.

Note that some other laptop manufacturers (notably Dell) have a similar “protection” mechanism.

It is not clear from your question what was the reason for removing the third pin (was the original connector damaged?). The solution to your problem is to restore its use, either by using an original power supply and/or finding an original connector, or by finding a third party power supply that supports the correct “third pin” protocol.